# 'Font' is an ambiguous reference between System.Drawing.Font and iTextSharp.text.Font

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

I am trying to export a formatted Pdf file using the code below.I tried to fully qualify the 'Font' but i still get the same error and even more. This error flagged after fully qualifying the 'Font' ,'Argument 1:cannot convert from 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont' to 'System.Drawing.FontFamily'.This is the code.

```
void ExportDataTableToPdf(DataTable dtaTable, String strPdfPath, string strHeader)
    {
        System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(strPdfPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        Document document = new Document();
        document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        document.Open();

        //Report header
        BaseFont bsHead = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        Font fsHead = new Font(bsHead, 16, 1, Color.Gray);  /***Red underlined code ***/
        Paragraph pfgHeading = new Paragraph();
        pfgHeading.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        pfgHeading.Add(new Chunk(strHeader.ToUpper(), fsHead));
        document.Add(pfgHeading);

        //Author
        Paragraph prgAuthor = new Paragraph();
        BaseFont btnAuthor = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        Font fsAuthor = new Font(btnAuthor, 8, 2, Color.Gray);  /***Red underlined code ***/
        prgAuthor.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        prgAuthor.Add(new Chunk("Author:2Deep", fsAuthor));
        prgAuthor.Add(new Chunk("\nRun Date:" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), fsAuthor));
        document.Add(prgAuthor);

        //Line separator
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Chunk(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0.0F, 100.0F, Color.Black, ,Element.ALIGN_LEFT)));
        document.Add(p);

        //line break
        document.Add(new Chunk("\n", fsHead));

        //Write Table
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dtaTable.Columns.Count);

        //Table Header
        BaseFont btnColumnHeader = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        Font fntColumnHeader = new Font(btnColumnHeader, 10, 1, Color.White);  /***Red underlined code ***/
        for (int i = 0; i < dtaTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();  /***Red underlined code ***/
            cell.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
            cell.AddElement(new Chunk(dtaTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToUpper(), fntColumnHeader));
            table.AddCell(cell);
        }

        //table data
        for (int i=0; i < dtaTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < dtaTable.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                table.AddCell(dtaTable.Rows[i][j].ToString());


            }
        }
        document.Add(table);
        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
        fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `using System.Drawing;` and `using 'iTextSharp.text.pdf;` at the top of your code file (or within the namespace definition).

Now, in `System.Drawing` there is a `Font` type, and likewise in `iTextSharp.text.pdf` there is also a `Font` object. Visual Studio is unable to determine which one you want to use, so you have to stop the situation being ambiguous.

You can do this in a number of ways:

1. Remove the unwanted using (if you're using nothing from `System.Drawing`, for example, remove the `using System.Drawing;` declaration).
2. Explicitly state the type you want to use in your code. Instead of `Font a = new Font()`, use `System.Drawing.Font a = new System.Drawing.Font();`
3. Alias the type with a `using` statement: `using TheFont = System.Drawing.Font` and then in your code write something like `TheFont = new TheFont();`